# Why would the canvas2d context no longer fill ellipses?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm working on a javascript game that simulates gravitational forces. It uses the HTML5 canvas element to draw 2D ellipses for planets. I test my game in Google Chrome. Here's a link to the game: http://gravitygame.hostingsiteforfree.com/index.php?page=playHTML

Up until May 24th, it worked just fine. However, after Chrome upgraded from 26.0.1410.64 to 27.0.1453.94, the filled ellipses are sometimes not drawn. It doesn't happen every time I load my game, and I've never gotten it to break while running locally.

Here's a screenshot of the game working:[image]

And here's a screenshot that shows it not filling the ellipses:[image]

I can't tell what's happening. I'll include the portion of the loop that draws all of the planets. I've modified it for readability.

```
    var i = bodies.length;
    while(i--){
    var I = bodies[i];
    var planetRad = (I.width/2)*_scale;
    if(_showTrails){
        //draw the planet's trail
    }
    if(//the planet is completely off the screen){
        //draw a red planet on the edge of the screen
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(nX, nY, 2.5, 0, TWOPI);
        ctx.fillStyle = offScreenColor;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = offScreenOutline;
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    else{
        //draw planet
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(nX, nY, (I.width/2)*_scale, 0, TWOPI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = I.bodyColor;
        ctx.fill();     
    }
    if(_showMotionVector){
        //draw a line from the center of a planet showing the direction and speed it's travelling
        ctx.strokeStyle = motionColor;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(I.getScX(), I.getScY());
        ctx.lineTo(I.motion.x * _scale * 12 + I.getScX(), I.motion.y * _scale * 12 + I.getScY());
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

Why would it suddenly break on occasion?

Comment: I ran across a similar problem with IE, so here's a try.  Is it fixed if you add ctx.closePath(); after the first arc in your example code?

Comment: That didn't work. Every once in a while I'm still able to get it to load it and the planets don't show up.

Comment: Unable to reproduce in Chrome or Canary (+ other browsers) (in FF panning didn't work for me btw). How do you trigger the animation loop?

Comment: It's inside the setInterval() function. (I knew about the panning issue in FF. I'm still getting around to that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look at your online code and discovered you are using `setInterval` for the animation loop.

This is most likely the reason as if the code is not able to finish calling the calcs etc. you run the risk of stacking calls - for context that means you can have path's that reset each other.

Try first to replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`. You will of course need to retrigger it again from within the code - better yet, put everything in a function with a setTimeout at the end of that function, ie.:

```
function animate() {
    //... calcs and redraws which you have in setInterval
    setTimeout(animate, 0);
}
animate();
```

I use 0 for timeout here for this test. `setTimeout/setInterval` won't sync to screen refresh rate in any case.

If that works then you know the reason. The next step would be to replace it with `requestAnimationFrame`,  but let me know how it goes.

In an attempt to illustrate the problem we can look at this illustration:

[image: Working interval]

Each block represent a function within the loop, and one loop is one color. Remember that `setInterval` calls at *fixed* intervals while `setTimeout` calls *relative* to when it's called. In this example the functions perform within the time budget so everything goes well.

In the next illustration:

[image: Stacking interval]

the spending is outside the budget so `setInterval` is called again and queues up next call to the second loop before the first has finished. When the queue is processed between the calls you end up risking having two functions working on the context at the "same time" (or comes in a different order than you might expect).

Javascript is of course single-threaded so they do not execute at the same time, but one is held at wait - if the first block for next queue is called before the last block has time to be called then the first block will modify the context and perhaps even change the path before the last call of the previous call is invoked. Over time the lag-behind will increase and potentially (unless some extra available processing resources resolves the queue now and then - on a busy system this is less likely to happen) become worse and worse as more stacking occur.

Ie, in this case you could have lines added to the context with `beginPath()` before `arc` got filled.

(hope that made any sense...)

Using `setTimeout` will prevent this as it won't be executed before all calls in the animation loop has returned. The better option is to use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) as this will call in sync with the screen-refresh rate, also when possible. It's  more low-level and therefor also more efficient.

Another path (no pun intended) is to use [Web-workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) to do the calculations. This will be multi-threaded and can increase overall performance as a web-worker does not affect the UI thread.

Comment: My initial test of setTimeout() seems to work. I'll have to try it out on a couple of computers before I'm convinced, though. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: Looks good so far. I had to make the change you mentioned in your first comment in addition to the switch from setInterval to setTimeout.